# Xcode 4.2.1. Simulator issue

Tags: iphone, xcode

App runs on simulator on my MacBook Air, but not on iMac. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall, but no difference. I see 16_dyld_dyld_start in xcode for Thread 1. App also runs on device.

Comment: Both  Xcode version are same on iMac and macbook?

Comment: What does "not run" mean? Post the console log and stack trace of the failure.

Comment: Yes. Both versions are the same. But different result. I see my own app startup screen, but then everything seem to hang. I will post console log soon. Seem to stop before I can set any breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I have enabled Zombie objects to get more debug information. At the same time I checked "guard malloc". It seems to be the "guard malloc" feature that gets the simulator to hang. When I unchecked "guard malloc" the simulator continues properly. I saw no relevant info in the console.